# 'Could not read from remote repository' on NPM install (@react-navigation/bottom-tabs)

Tags: git, npm, react-navigation

I am trying to install the react navigation bottom tabs package,

`npm install @react-navigation/bottom-tabs`

but I am getting this error:

```
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/react-navigation/bottom-tabs.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/********/.npm/_logs/2021-06-13T15_04_43_298Z-debug.log
```

I checked out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43360234/could-not-read-from-remote-repository-on-npm-install-from-github-public-repo) but wasn't able to solve my problem. What exactly does this error mean?

Additionally, when I just try to clone the repo

`git clone ssh://git@github.com/react-navigation/bottom-tabs.git`

I get this same error. Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but have you setup `ssh` keys locally?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Permission+denied+publickey

Comment: Additionally, when I just try to clone the repo I get this same error. Is there something I can do to fix this - There's no such repo. Not sure why npm is trying to clone such a repo. It should install a package from npm registry. Maybe you have faulty package.json. Can you post it?